# How to fix "E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list ([option] not assignment) \n E:The list of sources could not be read

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am following the process to download MongoDB on Linux 22.04 LTS. But, after typing

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-
by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mongodb.gpg]
https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0
multiverse" >>
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list'
```

in the terminal and ran the command
`sudo apt-get update`, I received the error listed in the title.

Comment: The error message is complaining about the content of the mongo.list file.  What does that look like?

Comment: Run `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list` and post the output please.

Comment: It looks exactly like the one specified in the response below.

Comment: deb [arch = amd64,arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mongodb.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse

Comment: You have extra spaces. See updated answer. Easy to miss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Malformed entry 1 in list file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291199/malformed-entry-1-in-list-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the command didn't add the entry correctly to your mongo.list file. If you open up the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list
```

It looks like you have extra spaces here:

```
deb [arch = amd64,arm64
```

but you need

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64
```

As per the [sources.list man pages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/sources.list.5.html):

> The format for two one-line-style entries using the deb and deb-src types is:

```
deb [ option1=value1 option2=value2 ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
deb-src [ option1=value1 option2=value2 ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
```

> If options should be provided they are separated by spaces and all of them together are enclosed by square brackets ([]) included in the line after the type separated from it with a space. If an option allows multiple values these are separated from each other with a comma (,). **An option name is separated from its value(s) by an equals sign (=).**

Make sure line 1 reads **exactly** like this:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mongodb.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

Save the file and close, then assuming the mongodb.gpg is stored in `/etc/apt/keyrings/` you should be OK.

As an aside, it would make more sense to have a `mongodb-org-6.0.list` instead of a `mongo.list` but that's just semantics.

Comment: It does exactly read like that.